# Generated HTML IMG not displaying - Provided Path Incorrect(?)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to write a code that would dynamically generate "gallery" based on the number of pictures user has uploaded to the web site on a particular date.
These pictures are stored on the VS Project Folder(ImageProject) inside a directory called UploadedPictures. This directory contains sub directories for each months and all days of the month.

When user clicks on a certain button. This gallery should be populated.

```
protected void InsertAttachments(int ID)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl Div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        HtmlGenericControl Img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
        try
        {
            string[] ImageArray = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedPictures"), "*_*_" + ID + "_*.jpeg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            try
            {
                foreach (var Picture in ImageArray)
                {
                    Div = new HtmlGenericControl("Div");
                    Div.Attributes["class"] = "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb";

                    Img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
                    Img.Attributes["class"] = "img-responsive";
                    Img.Attributes.Add("src", Picture);

                    IMGContainer.Controls.Add(Div);
                    Div.Controls.Add(Img);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

As can be seen from the code, I'm trying to generate new HTML elements based on the number of pictures that are found. These HTML elements are then added to IMGContainer Div.

The result after the button is clicked - the following HTML code is generated and nothing can be seen.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ImageProject\ImageProject\
    UploadedPictures\2015_12\2015_12_22\5_1_1213_1.jpeg">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ImageProject\ImageProject\
    UploadedPictures\2015_12\2015_12_22\5_1_1213_2.jpeg">
</div>
```

The problem is, there are no pictures being displayed, even through the provided path is correct and the pictures are not stored externally outside the project folder..

Furthermore, this provided path is visible both on test VM server and outside the work environment, for example, If I access the web site with my home PC.

In both cases this is the Error Message that I get when I check the Browser's Console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource:    
file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ImageProject/ImageProject/UploadedPictures/2015_12/2015_12_22/5_1_1213_1.jpeg
```

Does anyone have any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use relative path for image gallary rather than using absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use current directory reference

```
protected void InsertAttachments(int ID)
{
    HtmlGenericControl Div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    HtmlGenericControl Img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
    try
    {
        string[] ImageArray = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("./UploadedPictures"), "*_*_" + ID + "_*.jpeg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        try
        {
            foreach (var Picture in ImageArray)
            {
                Div = new HtmlGenericControl("Div");
                Div.Attributes["class"] = "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb";

                Img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
                Img.Attributes["class"] = "img-responsive";
                Img.Attributes.Add("src", Picture);

                IMGContainer.Controls.Add(Div);
                Div.Controls.Add(Img);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server code is generating local paths to the images, so when you publish the code to the internet and a client browser renders the page, it gets directions to load images that he can't reach.

You have to change the created urls to be relative to your hosted project, so any external client can reach them.

Comment: Thank you! Adding solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string MakeRelative(string filePath, string referencePath)
    {
        var fileUri = new Uri(filePath);
        var referenceUri = new Uri(referencePath);
        return referenceUri.MakeRelativeUri(fileUri).ToString();
    }
```